# Update a field in an Elm-lang record via dot function?

Tags: functional-programming, elm

Is it possible to update a field in an Elm record via a function (or some other way) without explicitly specifying the precise field name?

Example:

```
> fields = { a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 }
> updateField fields newVal fieldToUpdate = { fields | fieldToUpdate <- newVal }
> updateField fields 5 .a -- does not work
```

#### UPDATE:

To add some context, I'm trying to DRY up the following code:

```
UpdatePhraseInput contents ->
  let currentInputFields = model.inputFields
  in { model | inputFields <- { currentInputFields | phrase <- contents }}

UpdatePointsInput contents ->
  let currentInputFields = model.inputFields
  in { model | inputFields <- { currentInputFields | points <- contents }}
```

Would be really nice if I could call a mythical `updateInput` function like this:

```
UpdatePhraseInput contents -> updateInput model contents .phrase
UpdatePointsInput contents -> updateInput model contents .points
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Rolling your own update function

Yes, though perhaps not as nicely as *getting* from a field. But the idea is the same, you write a function that simply uses the record update syntax:

```
setPhrase r v = { r | phrase <- v }
setPoints r v = { r | points <- v }
updInputFields r f = { r | inputFields <- f r.inputFields }
```

Then you can write:

```
UpdatePhraseInput contents -> updInputFields model (flip setPhrase contents)
UpdatePointsInput contents -> updInputFields model (flip setPoints contents)
```

## The `Focus` library

When you combine `field` and `fieldSet`, you get something like a [`Focus`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/focus/1.0.1/Focus). Although that library works for more things than just records. Here's an example of what this would look like using `Focus`:

```
phrase = Focus.create .phrase (\upd r -> { r | phrase <- upd r.phrase })
points = Focus.create .points (\upd r -> { r | points <- upd r.points })
inputFields = Focus.create .inputFields (\upd r -> { r | inputFields <- upd r.inputFields})
```

Then you can write:

```
UpdatePhraseInput contents -> Focus.set (inputFields => phrase) contents model
UpdatePointsInput contents -> Focus.set (inputFields => points) contents model
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you could define a function which could select which field gets updated, but you cannot.

See [This article](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2015/11/06/functionally-updating-record-types-in-elm/), which explains why it's not currently possible to functionally update fields in a record in elm:

> "Seasoned functional programmers will surely have noticed that many of these concepts sound a lot like lenses, and Elm actually already has a lens-like library authored by Evan himself, called Focus. This, however, does not actually solve the problem: it requires manual description of setters just like the purely function based approach does."

...and the following [comment](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/1068#issuecomment-219115687) from the the creator of Elm explaining why [proposed support for this](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-compiler/issues/984) wasn't added with the recent changes to records:

> "I considered that and decided against it. I know that proposal. It's a language feature proposal, not a simple syntax thing"